# why is hook_access_node running three times?

Tags: 8, hooks

I'm working on a custom node access module. For this I'm working with hook_node_access hook (for the first time).

I want visitors to be able to view a node only when they are looking at them from the right domain. For this I have a content type `page`, in this content type I created a field `field_domain`.

Now I create a two nodes, `Node A` with field_domain value `d9-a.lcl` and `Node B` with field_domain value `d9-b.lcl`.

Now I wanted to create the module [based on the this tutorial](https://makedrupaleasy.com/articles/drupal-8-how-prevent-access-pages-anonymous-user). But before this I created a simple check to see if I can get the value from the field and current domain. So I wrote this:

```
function hook_access_node_access(NodeInterface $node, $op, $account)
{
    $type = $node->bundle();
    if ($type == 'page') {
        $currentDomain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $readerDomain = $node->field_domain->value;
        dpm($node->id());
        dpm('Current domain: ' . $currentDomain);
        dpm('Pages domain: ' . $readerDomain);
    }
}
```

Now going to `Node B` from domain `d9-b.lcl` made me expect to see three values. And the values I wanted to see are there but they get returned three times.

[image]

So for some reason the hook is called three times and I can't figure out why. Is it normal that this hook is called three times? And if it is is there a better way to do what I want?

Comment: Yes it’s perfectly usual for a node access hook to be hit multiple times in one request, check the `$op` parameter to see what you’re dealing with each time

Comment: If you want more details you can use debug_backtrace function and print the result (or use a debugger).

Comment: Thanks @Clive it was indeed running three times because of the three access levels view,update and delete foud in $op.

Comment: Those three access check manage the tabs you can see or not on your content (view / edit / delete tabs)

Comment: @Clive why do you answer in a comment? Please give the answer in the proper place so that can be accepted and this question marked as answered. Thanks

Comment: That’s ok @dxvargas, no time to write a proper answer. Feel free to write one up and get it accepted

Comment: Done @Clive, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it’s perfectly usual for a node access hook to be hit multiple times in one request, check the $op parameter to see what you’re dealing with each time.

Checks may be done for different $op values like view,update and delete.

(Answer from @Clive in comments, posted here as answer after his advice. Please see question's comments.)